# Accessing properties from an object created in IB - Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, properties

I have a class called `NetworkSection` with a corresponding object created in IB. In the interface, I have one NSMatrix property called `IVBSpecificationMenu`. I would like to access that NSMatrix object through the ResultSection class, also initialized in IB.

It seems that I'm doing something wrong. I've created the property, linked the outlet to the NetworkSection object, imported the NetworkSection.h file, yet in the ResultSection implementation, the IVBSpecificationMenu object doesn't seem to be available.

**Section.h:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NetworkSection : NSObjectController { 

    IBOutlet NSTextField *IVBhostPerNetwork;
    IBOutlet NSTextField *IVBamountOfNetworks;
}

@property (retain) IBOutlet NSMatrix *IVBSpecificationMenu;

- (IBAction)enableSpecificationTextField:(id)sender;

@end
```

**ResultSection.h:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "NetworkSection.h"

@interface ResultSection : NSObjectController{

    IBOutlet NetworkSection *NetworkSection;

}

- (IBAction)CalculateResults:(id)sender;
- (void)SpecificationSection;
- (void)subnetMaskSection;
@end
```

Is this the right way to access properties from another class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this helps...but what screams at me is the name of your variable in the line `IBOutlet NetworkSection *NetworkSection;` of your `ResultSection` interface file.

Maybe the variable name (`NetworkSection`) is clashing with the type name (also `NetworkSection`). Try changing the variable name to something like `networkSection` or `_networkSection`.